# Angular ngbTypeahead gives [Object] error

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

My component.html (Input field)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" [ngbTypeahead]="recommends"
    name="searchQuery" typeaheadOptionField="username">
```

My component.ts

```
  this.recommends = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchText) => this.stats.getSearchCompletion(searchText))
      );
}
```

My getSearchCompletion function

```
  getSearchCompletion(searchQuery) {
   if(searchQuery) return this.http.post(backendURL + '/my/route', { searchQuery: searchQuery }, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
```

The repsonse is returned in a format like this:

```
[{
 "username": "test"

},
{
 "username": "test2"
}]
```

I get the following error:
[To Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo2F9.png)

I guess it is because my server response has multiple objects inside a list. But how do I bind the ngbTypeahead to for example username? I tried `typeaheadOptionField="username"` which gives me the error. The list pops up but has no entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some of javascript skills to convert the response into plain array of strings, something like this

```js
   if(searchQuery) return this.http.post(backendURL + '/my/route', { searchQuery: searchQuery }, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(map(res => {
   let arr:string[] = [];
   res.json().forEach(x=>{
       arr.push(x['username']);
   });

    return arr;

   }));
```

This is based on assumption that your api response is in this format

```
[{ "username": "test"},{ "username": "test2"}]
```

Which is an array of objects.

Thanks.

Comment: I get an error of: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Response'

Comment: Mark the question as answered then, so that it may help other users.